# Electromagnetic duality

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations, lorentz-symmetry, duality

A key aspect of modern physics is the mapping of theories or different descriptions of a theory into a one-to-one correspondence. As I am trying to further understand the electromagnetic field tensor, the Lorentz group and field theories, I have come across the recurring theme of duality. In terms of the free Maxwell theory could somebody explain on the self-duality.

Namely, discuss the mutual exchange of the electric and magnetic field, which leaves the Maxwell equations invariant. An example applying the Lorentz transformation to the Electric Field would be helpful.

Comment: Potentially worth a read: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Lectures/EDC.pdf Definitely worth a read:http://users.ictp.it/~pub_off/lectures/lns007/Strassler/Strassler.pdf

Comment: When you find a duality, you are very excited. This is the first and justifyed reaction. But the point is, that it is, in some sense, a bad new. This means, that what you think be a precise and unique description of the reality, is not. This means, that the basic concepts that you were using (like space-time, etc..) are not so basic. This means that the maths you are using for describing some reality are not the best maths (and best maths are related to a best physical description of the reality), even if they are good maths.

Comment: So, a discover of a duality, means that there is a better theory hidden somewhere. Easy to say, hard to find...

Comment: Parker, E: Conversations on Electric and Magnetic Fields in the Cosmos http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8454.html
has several conversations about it.

Comment: Digestible slides by Ed Witten titled "Duality, Spacetime and Quantum Mechanics" [duality slides](http://online.kitp.ucsb.edu/plecture/witten/).